# How to validate input data in view form?

Tags: sql, yii2

I have sql schema like this [image: this].

I found the way to displaying, sorting and filtering model relations on a GridView [here](http://Displaying,%20Sorting%20and%20Filtering%20Model%20Relations%20on%20a%20GridView) and now almost everything works fine. So here is my issue [image]

As you can see on the screenshot, I can create two rows with items 'Nokia' and use the same 'Parametr2', which is incorrect. How can i validate my data while i creating new 'Strategy Options' row? [image]

Comment: please explain more and add what you trying ?

Comment: @vishuB I cant add what im trying cause i dont even know which way i have to go to solve this issue. What can i explain is that i want to add my personal validation error, that will pop out when i will try to add new row with already exist 'paramert' & 'strategy' combination.

Comment: The forms in your view will be validated, as you can see they are both green in the last screenshot. If your question is regarding a unique together validation, your title is a bit off. Have a look at the "unique together"-example here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator

Comment: @Jørgen thank you. Your comment helps me a lot.